# Projectile flight range in different atmosphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

If we change atmosphere density from 1 atm to 50 atm, how much would cannon's firing range change? Assuming round ball as projectile, 2 km effective range in current atmosphere.

There seems to be two positions on this issue.

One is that range will decrease linearly as pressure increase, and will become 40 m. Because drag formula has density in power 1 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics) , because newton approximation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth

Another view is that range will decrease as sqrt(pressure change times) times. So range will become 280 m. I wasnt able to find reason for this view, but it is more popular.

It is from a debate from world building SE, some help from people knowing physics will be appriciated to solve our conflict.

Comment: I assume the pressure from the explosive charger is still much larger than that of the 50 atmopsheres and can be neglected?

Comment: @DKNguyen yes, pressure in the cannon from gunpowder is significantly more

Comment: The drag decreases linearly due to the straight density variable in the drag equation, but the range will decrease differently because there is a squared velocity term in the drag equation. Changing the density changes the drag which changes moment-to-moment velocity which ultimately influences the range, and since this is not linear neither will the change in range. It should pop out via some calculus.

Comment: @DKNguyen my logic is that total change in speed is the same. We can take a small part of speed change, from 500 m/s to 490 m/s. This speed drop will change time needed for it linearly with pressure. And same for all other parts of speed. If all parts are scaled the same ratio, so does the whole changes with the same ratio.

Comment: Linear multipliers in squared terms don't end up linear. If you double the density that doubles the the drag which doubles the deceleration one moment. Then in the next you are working with a velocity that was decelerated twice the amount it otherwise would have been. In this new moment, the drag force will be 1/4 what it would have otherwise been. It's best just to do the math and look at the numbers because for it to be linear these factors would all have to cancel out perfectly and I doubt that they do.

Comment: @DKNguyen you offer to integrate over change of time, which is complicated. I offer to integrate over change of speed, that I think is easier.

Comment: I don't see how you are going to end up with a distance number by integrating over speed (actually we need acceleration here because drag is a force) in the absence of time seeing as how \$$d = \int v dt\ = \int\int a dt$$. What does integrating over speed even mean?

Comment: I'm trying it now and it's pretty weird since there is a velocity in the acceleration function but you integrate acceleration to get velocity. I think doing it via impulse might be best because I don't know if the velocity in the acceleration function is the moment-to-moment velocity or the initial velocity.

Comment: Momentum has the same issue because the drag force is dependent on the velocity but then the velocity is dependent on the drag force. You know what? I think this is one of those weird problems like the propeller math problem the Wright Brother's had where the input affects the output and the output affects the input, and not so easy to solve analytically. Doing it numerically would be simpler.